# How to Sort a Model Based on a Property in IList<T> within that Model

Tags: list, linq, sorting, .net-core, lambda

This is a bit more complex than other questions. I have a Model that encapsulates an IList. Within each IList item there are multiple Lists. This makes it VERY difficult to flatten the entire dataset. I need to both filter and/or sort the highest IList items based on a value in that Ilist. So as an example, lets say my structure is as follows:

```
public class ScorecardModel
{
  //Measure Data
  public IList<ProgramScorecardModel> ProgramScorecardModel { get; set; }
                
}

public class ProgramScorecardModel
{
    public string programId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? reportingDate { get; set; }
    public string programName { get; set; }

    //Measure Data
    public IList<Sales_ViewModel> Sales_ViewModel { get; set; }
    public IList<Employees_ViewModel> Employees_ViewModel { get; set; }
    public IList<Locations_ViewModel> Locations_ViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

My scorecard returns all of the programs and their respective data. What I want to do is sort/filter the ProgramScorecard models based on the programId.

Here is how I call the queries that populate the scorecard.

```
ScorecardModel scorecard = new ScorecardModel();
scorecard = _adoSqlService.GetScorecard();
```

I want to call the following Sort function:

```
private ScorecardModel sortScorecard(ScorecardModel scorecardList, string sortField, string sortDirection)
{
    IQueryable<ScorecardModel> sortedScorecard = scorecardList.AsQueryable();
    sortedScorecard = sortedScorecard.OrderBy(sortField + " " + sortDirection);
    return sortedScorecard;
}
```

The problem is that the scorecardlist is not enumerable. If I change the functions to use this then the scorecard loading (GetScorecard) throws errors.

```
IEnumerable<ScorecardModel> scorecard = null;
scorecard = _adoSqlService.GetScorecard();

private IEnumerable<ScorecardModel> sortScorecard(IEnumerable<ScorecardModel> scorecardList, string sortField, string sortDirection)
{
  IQueryable<ScorecardModel> sortedScorecard = scorecardList.AsQueryable();
  sortedScorecard = sortedScorecard.OrderBy(sortField + " " + sortDirection);
  return sortedScorecard;
}
```

I've tried changing the GetScorecard routine, but I can't get the following to work:

```
public IList<ScorecardModel> GetScorecard()
{
   string programid;
   string reportingdate = "2/1/2022";
   IList<ProgramViewModel> proglist = new List<ProgramViewModel>();
   proglist = GetPrograms();
   IList <ScorecardModel> scorecardData = new List<ScorecardModel>();
   scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel = new List<ProgramScorecardModel>(); <---This Line Here, ProgramScorecardModel is not able to be a list
   int i = 0;
   foreach (var p in proglist)
   {
       ProgramScorecardModel programData = new ProgramScorecardModel();
       programData.programId = p.programId;
       programData.programName = p.programName;
       programid = p.programId;
       programData.Sales_ViewModel = new List<Sales_ViewModel>(GetSalesData(programid, reportingdate));
       programData.Employees_ViewModel = new List<Employees_ViewModel>(GetEmployeesData(programid, reportingdate));
       programData.Locations_ViewModel = new List<Locations_ViewModel>(GetLocationsData(programid, reportingdate));
       scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel.Add(programData);
       i++;
    }
    return scorecardData;
}
```

How can I make the entire scorecardData and scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel an enemrable object?

Assuming I get this working as an enumerable object, will I be able to sort AND Filter on scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel[x].programName values?

**Additional Info**
This is how I currently populate the scorecard model

```
public ScorecardModel GetScorecard()
{
    string programid;
    string reportingdate = "2/1/2022";
    IList<ProgramViewModel> proglist = new List<ProgramViewModel>();
    proglist = GetPrograms();
    ScorecardModel scorecardData = new ScorecardModel();
    scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel = new List<ProgramScorecardModel>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var p in proglist)
    {
        ProgramScorecardModel programData = new ProgramScorecardModel();
        programData.programId = p.programId;
        programData.programName = p.programName;
        programid = p.programId;
        programData.Locations_ViewModel = new List<Locations_ViewModel>(GetLocationData(programid, reportingdate));
        programData.Employees_ViewModel = new List<Employees_ViewModel>(GetEmployeeData(programid, reportingdate));
        programData.Sales_ViewModel = new List<Sales_ViewModel>(GetSalesData(programid, reportingdate));

        scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel.Add(programData);   
        i++; //This is used in some other code I have removed for simplification
    }
    return scorecardData;
}
```

The end result is this:
ScorecardModel
      ProgramScorecardModel[i]
              Programid
              Locations_ViewModel
              Employees_ViewModel
              Locations_ViewModel
      ProgramScorecardModel[i]
              Programid
              Locations_ViewModel
              Employees_ViewModel
              Locations_ViewModel
      ProgramScorecardModel[i]
              Programid
              Locations_ViewModel
              Employees_ViewModel
              Locations_ViewModel

Here is an oversimplification of how I'm using the scorecard model:

```
for (int i = 0; i < @Model.ProgramScorecardModel.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 5px">@Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].programName</td>


        @{string results = Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Sales_ViewModel[0].rating;

            <td colspan="3" class="tdtooltip @(results == "R" ? "measure_red" : results == "Y" ? "measure_yellow" : results == "G" ? "measure_green" : results == "NR" ? "measure_nr" : results == "NS" ? "measure_ns" : "measure_na")">
                @Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Sales_ViewModel[0].rating
                @if (@Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Sales_ViewModel[0].comments.Length > 0)
                {
                    <span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Sales_ViewModel[0].comments)</span>
                }
            </td>
        }

        @{results = Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Employees_ViewModel[0].rating;

            <td colspan="3" class="tdtooltip @(results == "R" ? "measure_red" : results == "Y" ? "measure_yellow" : results == "G" ? "measure_green" : results == "NR" ? "measure_nr" : results == "NS" ? "measure_ns" : "measure_na")">
                @Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Employees_ViewModel[0].rating
                @if (@Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Employees_ViewModel[0].comments.Length > 0)
                {
                    <span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Employees_ViewModel[0].comments)</span>
                }
            </td>
        }

        @{ results = Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Locations_ViewModel[0].rating;

            <td colspan="3" class="tdtooltip @(results == "R" ? "measure_red" : results == "Y" ? "measure_yellow" : results == "G" ? "measure_green" : results == "NR" ? "measure_nr" : results == "NS" ? "measure_ns" : "measure_na")">
                @Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Locations_ViewModel[0].rating
                @if (@Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Locations_ViewModel[0].comments.Length > 0)
                {
                    <span class="tooltiptext">@Html.Raw(Model.ProgramScorecardModel[i].Locations_ViewModel[0].comments)</span>
                }
            </td>
        }
       
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Hello. I am sorry to say I am having a hard time understanding your code. One thing that is unclear to me is how you expect to sort a list by a property of an item in a property that is also a list. Do you expect each `ProgramScorecardModel` to have the same `programId` within a single `ScorecardModel`?
Also, the lines
`IList <ScorecardModel> scorecardData = new List<ScorecardModel>();`
`scorecardData.ProgramScorecardModel = new List<ProgramScorecardModel>();`
do not make much sense as `scorecardData` is a list, it will never have the `ProgramScorecardModel` property.

Comment: @FrancescoD.M. The scorecard model has a list of programscorecardmodels. Each programscorecardmodel represents a single program. Each Programscorcardmodel has a subset of lists of data for that program. So what you have is Scorecard.ProgramScorecardModel[i].programid, where the i is an incrementing number.

Comment: Ok. And the end result you want to achieve is to sort exactly what entity by what property? What I am understanding is you want the `ProgramScorecardModel` property to be sorted by `programId` correct? Also, `GetPrograms()` is what is getting the programs from the db correct? So `ProgramViewModel` is the type returned by the orm.
From what I am understanding you are not looking for a way to have the sorting work at the db level but you want to apply it later on. Is this also correct?

Comment: @FrancescoD.M. I want to be able to sort the ProgramScorecardModels  by programId. I don't want to do this at the DB level. I'll be doing the sort using an OrderBy.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. Give me some time and I will try to formulate an answer.

Comment: What package are you using and what namespace are you importing to be able to use `OrderBy` and pass in the `string` like in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the answer there are a couple things I did not understand. Maybe we can figure it out together. For now I will post what is a starting point to get things working.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var scorecard = GetScorecard();
        var sortedScorecard = scorecard.WithSortedPrograms("programId", "ascending");
    }
    
    public static ScorecardModel GetScorecard()
    {
        var proglist = new List<ProgramViewModel>();
        // proglist = GetPrograms();
        
        var scorecardData = new List<ProgramScorecardModel>();
        foreach (var p in proglist)
        {
          var programData = new ProgramScorecardModel();
          programData.ProgramId = p.ProgramId;
          scorecardData.Add(programData);
        }
        
        var scorecard = new ScorecardModel();
        scorecard.ProgramScorecardModel = scorecardData;
        return scorecard;
    }
}

public class ScorecardModel
{
  public List<ProgramScorecardModel> ProgramScorecardModel { get; set; }
    
  public ScorecardModel WithSortedPrograms(string sortField, string sortDirection)
  {
      var sortedModel = new ScorecardModel();
      // sortedModel.ProgramScorecardModel = ProgramScorecardModel.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortField + " " + sortDirection);
      sortedModel.ProgramScorecardModel = ProgramScorecardModel.OrderBy(x => x.ProgramId).ToList();
      return sortedModel;
  }
}

public class ProgramScorecardModel
{
    public string ProgramId { get; set; }
}

public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public string ProgramId { get; set; }
}
```

I was not able to find a `OrderBy` method for `IQueryable<T>` that accepts a `string`. That is why for now I wrote the `x => x.ProgramId` expression.

There are many improvements I would personally make to your code though as I find it a bit messy. Once we find the correct solution to your problem, if you want, we can look at a different ways to approach this.

Comment: The only reason I tried to return <code>IList<ScorecardModel></code> was to make it inumerable. I will post how I CURRENTLY do the GetScorecard. what i want is the ability to populate the Scorecard model, and then just keep passing it to an OrderBy to sort instead of having to requery the database.

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer with something that might work. The idea now is that when you need the programs to be sorted you can call the `WithSortedPrograms` method and get a new `ScorecardModel` with the list sorted to your liking.
I still do not understand what method you are using as `OrderBy` passing a `string` though.

Comment: @FlyFish I saw your edits on the question. I think now my answer can give you a solution. I still do not think it is ideal but I first want to solve the problem. Then if you want we can talk about how to solve it in what is in my opinion a better way.

Comment: After looking at your code, I think I found a flaw in my entire process. In order for any of this to work, I would need to be able to pass a complex model from the view to the controller. From all I have seen, while it could be done, it looks to be quite cumbersome. Since I have to requery the database to build the new model, I can just as easily do the sorting there. I don't see a benefit of using the OrderBy if I have to requery the DB to get the data anyway.

Comment: @FlyFish yes, I agree that the way things are done now is very probably not optimal.
The thing is, if you need different sorting behaviours on the same set of data then it might make sense to retrieve the data unsorted and then sort in memory. Usually though we always try to sort at the db level, especially if there is some filtering and perhaps paging to be done. Unfortunately without knowing more about your application it is very hard for me to make useful suggestions.